# Delay PHP execution until JavaScript cookie set?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to delay PHP execution until a cookie is set through JavaScript. The code is below, I trimmed the `createCookie` JavaScript function for simplicity (I've tested the function itself and it works).

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["test"])) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            // createCookie script
            createCookie("test", 1, 3600);
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    // Reload the page to ensure cookie was set
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["test"])) {
        header("Location: http://localhost/");
    }
}
?>
```

At first I had no idea why this didn't work, however after using `microtime()` I figured out that the PHP after the `<script>` was executing *before* the jQuery ready function. I reduced my code significantly to show a simple version that is answerable, I am well aware that I am able to use `setcookie()` in PHP, the requirements for the cookie are client-side.

I understand mixing PHP and JavaScript is incorrect, but any help on how to make this work (is there a PHP delay? - I tried `sleep()`, didn't work and didn't think it would work, since the scripts would be delayed as well) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done within a single request. PHP runs first, then JavaScript. Even incremental loading won't help, because cookies are sent via headers and those have already been sent by the time PHP runs.

However, you can let the JavaScript set the cookie and then reload the page once it's done by using `location.reload()`. PHP would then only need to print the JavaScript, like so:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["test"])) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            // createCookie script
            createCookie("test", 1, 3600);
            // reload the page, which would send the cookie at the next request
            location.reload();
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    // stop execution and wait for JavaScript to call you again.
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I like that idea as I have no AJAX experience. I will try this out in the actual code. Location reload is slightly slower than a header I believe so I'm guessing it might flicker sometimes.

Comment: @Adam184 I don't think you can really compare `Location:` header and `location.reload()` that way; they do different things.

Comment: +1 Thank you! I was able to get it to work with a little tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

It is not ***impossible*** to do what you are trying to do, as other answers have stated, but it is also not trivial and seriously a bad idea for your server to wait per-request for the client to "set a cookie."

But it can be done.

1. PHP code would write a `<script>` block for setting the cookie.
2. PHP code would begin an idle loop, monitoring a **session** variable. Not a cookie. The cookies for the PHP script executing are already set and are not going to change by JavaScript.
3. JavaScript block written in #1 would also need to make an AJAX call to the server. The PHP script it calls should set the cookie you care about, but also set the session variable #2 cares about.
4. The original script, monitoring the session, should wake up and continue as you planned.

While PHP *does* execute before JavaScript, all browsers incrementally load the HTML/CSS/JavaScript content generated by PHP (or any server-side language). Because of the incremental loading, it is possible for your PHP script to delay for JavaScript to do something (as outlined above) before continuing. But your server is going to have a lot of headache to deal with, such as how long to wait for JavaScript to break the idle loop in #2 if the JavaScript request never comes through, etc.

This is not a normal execution flow for a standard webpage. Unless you really need this, perhaps consider this a proof-of-concept answer.

Comment: I ended up using a `timeout` function and a separate `location.replace()` in JavaScript seemed to have fixed a bunch of things. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

PHP executes first in its entirety on the server. It then sends the final HTML/Javascript/CSS output to the browser. The browser receives this and executes any Javascript.

It is **fundamentally impossible** to do what you're trying to do with that code. PHP and Javascript run at completely different times in completely different environments. You need to start another request to the server once Javascript set the cookie to start *another* PHP script. Redirect using Javascript or look into AJAX.

Comment: I see, so the AJAX request would be in the <script> function, the header would have to have requirements from the AJAX part. Never learned AJAX, but I will search Google and hopefully find something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute JavaScript before PHP, you'll have to divide it into two requests.  You can load your JavaScript in one request, and execute an Ajax request after your cookie is set.  Keep in mind that all server-side code is processed before the client-side code will be executed.

I have to ask though.. why do you want to do it this way?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be set in PHP with [`setcookie`](http://php.net/setcookie)

```
setcookie("test",1,time()+3600);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Kolink, unfortunately the cookie requirements are client-side. I wrote I knew about `setcookie()` in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP executes on the server-side, the JS on the client-side. In a single GET request from the browser, the PHP will **always** execute before the JS.